# POST submit to mysql using php the value from append javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, append

I'm trying to POST submit the data to mysql using php from append javascript.

Here's the modal where data come from append which is in php.

```
                            <tr onload="calculate()">

                                <?php

                                foreach ($conn->query("SELECT * FROM panapricelist") as $info){

                                    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' id='promotitle' name='check' value='".$info['ProductId']."' ></td>";
                                    echo "<td><textarea rows='4' cols='7' maxlength='60'  name='pcode' class='pcode' id='ProductCode' disabled>".$info['ProductCode']."</textarea></td>";
                                    echo "<td><br><textarea rows='5' cols='40' maxlength='50' name='puse' class='productuse' id='productuse' disabled>".$info['ProductUse']." </textarea></td>";
                                    echo "<td><br><textarea rows='4' cols='50' maxlength='50' name='pdesc' class='description' id='productDesc' disabled>".$info['ProductDesc']."</textarea></td>";
                                    echo "<td id='msrp'><textarea rows='4' cols='10' maxlength='50' name='Msrp' class='msrp' id='productMsrp' disabled>".$info['Msrp']."</textarea></td>";
                                    echo "<td style='width: 10%;'><textarea rows='4' cols='10' name='cost' maxlength='50' class='cost' id='cost' disabled>".$info['DealerPhp']."</textarea></td></tr>";
                                }
                                ?>

                            </tbody>
```

Here's the append js from modal to table.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#button_add").click(function() {
                var favorite = [];
                $.each($("input[name='check']:checked").each( function() {
                    // favorite.push($(this).val());

                    var getRow = $(this).parents('tr'); //variable for the entire row
                    var value =  (getRow.find('td:eq(1)').html()); // Product Code
                    var value1 = (getRow.find('td:eq(2)').html()); // for Suggested Product Use
                    var value2 = (getRow.find('td:eq(3)').html()); // for product Description
                    var value3 = (getRow.find('td:eq(4)').html()); // for MSRP PHP
                    var value4 = (getRow.find('td:eq(5)').html()); // for Dealer PHP
                    var value5 = (getRow.find('td:eq(0)').html()); // for Dealer PHP

                    $('#item-row').append('<tr><td class="item-name"><textarea value="'+ value +'</textarea></td><td class="item-name"><textarea class="check" name="check[]" value= "' + value1 + ' </textarea> </td><td class="item-name"><textarea value= "' + value2 +' </textarea></td><td class="item-name"><textarea value= "' + value3 + ' </textarea>  </td><td><textarea name="Msrp" value="' + value4 + '</textarea></td><td class="item-name"><textarea class="qty" id="qty" name="qty[]"> </textarea></td><td class="item-name"><textarea id="price" class="price" name="price[]" disabled></textarea></td></tr>');    
                }));


            });


        });
```

Questions is. how can i POST submit to mysql using PHP PDO the value come from append javascript??

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to put any input data inside of a form, then create a PHP script that handles the POST request and INSERTS the data into your MySQL database.

Your form tag should look something like this:

`<form class="post-form" action="script_that_handles_post.php" method="post">`

So, you'll want to use `$_POST['']`. For example, the `name` in your first table row is `name="check"`, you'll use `$_POST['name']` to get the value of that field. Do that for each field that you want to store. Preferably, you should store each of those in their own variables or an array.

Then, for your AJAX you'll have to include the library somehow. If you aren't already, put this in your footer below the jquery source:

`<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>`

Now you can add your AJAX POST request. Here's some code that should do it:

```
$(".post-form").submit(function (event) {
    var $form = $(this);
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();
    request = $.ajax({
        url:$form.attr('action'),
        type:'POST',
        data: serializedData
    });
    request.fail(function (jqXHR, errorThrown){
        console.error(
            "Error: " + errorThrown
        );
    });
    request.always(function () {
        $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

What this code is doing is taking the `action` path of your form and posting the data from the inputs of the fields there.

I hope this helps.